# How do I send a notification email as soon as file is uploaded from the node add/edit form?

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks, emails

I have a media video content type that has a video file field (takes a file), name, and air date. The video files are saved on amazon S3 not locally.
I want to monitor the files that are uploaded and get an email (that has the file name, file size, and URL) every time a file of 100MB or more is uploaded even before the node is saved when the user is still on the add/edit form.
How can I do that I looked into `hook_entity_insert` and `file_presave` or another option?
But I am a bit confused as to which one will be the best and how to implement it.

Comment: You could look at `hook_file_validate()`. Though if this is a standard Drupal file field it might be preemptive to send an email before entity save in case the user decides to switch the file before entity save?

Comment: hook_node_insert sounds good, get the file, check its size and programmatically send the mail you want.

Comment: @Prestosaurus, I want an email sent as soon as the file is uploaded to S3. Whether the file is changed or not after upload or the node is saved or not. I just want a way to track the big files uploaded to S3. Thanks

Comment: @leymannx hook_node_insert is related to the node itself which does not work if the user changes files before saving the node. I want to track the files uploaded whether the file is changed or not after upload or whether the node is saved or not. Thanks

Comment: Does this have to be implemented in Drupal? AWS has many options to monitor S3. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/monitoring-overview.html

Comment: Then go for hook_node_presave. Form is submitted and the node is about to get created/updated in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the AWS notifications and go over and compare the different hooks suggested. I will post the solution I used.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I end up using @cilefen suggestion: AWS notification